# Solving polynomials using De Moivre's theorem

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

Given $\cos 4\theta=8\cos^4\theta−8\cos^2\theta+1$, solve $16x^4-16x^2+1=0$.

The textbook's answers are $x=\pm\cos\dfrac{\pi}{12},\pm\cos\dfrac{5\pi}{12}$. I managed to get two of the four answers and i can not figure out what i did wrong.

**My Attempt**

Let $x=\cos\theta$

$16\cos^4\theta-16\cos^2\theta+1=0$

$2(8\cos^4\theta-8\cos^2\theta+1)=1$

$2\cos4\theta=1$

$\cos4\theta=\dfrac{1}{2}$

$\cos4\theta=\cos\dfrac{\pi}{3}$

$\therefore4\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{3}+k\pi$, for any integer k

I chose $0\le k \le 3$ as the other solutions would repeat its values for x.

$\theta=\dfrac{\pi}{12},\dfrac{\pi}{3},\dfrac{7\pi}{12},\dfrac{5\pi}{6}$

$\therefore x=\cos\dfrac{\pi}{12},\cos\dfrac{\pi}{3},\cos\dfrac{7\pi}{12},\cos\dfrac{5\pi}{6}$

$x=\cos\dfrac{\pi}{12},\cos\dfrac{\pi}{3},-\cos\dfrac{5\pi}{12},\cos\dfrac{5\pi}{6}$

Comment: By substituting $x=\cos(\theta)$ you're limiting the domain of $x$ to $[-1,1]$

Comment: You can also check your solution putting $y=x^2$ .You get a quadratic polynomial easily solvable .

Comment: Though this equation had all four roots in $[-1,1]$

Comment: I had forgotten about the domain. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

$$\cos4θ=\cfrac{1}{2}$$
$$\cos4θ=cos\cfrac{\pi}{3}$$
$$\therefore4θ=\cfrac{\pi}{3}+k\pi$$

This contains some errors

The $\cos$ and the $\sin$ function take each value two times in the interval $[0,2\pi]$ except $1$ and $-1$.
So the following holds:
$$\cos \phi=\cos (2\pi-\phi)$$
The period of these trigonometric functions is $2\pi$, and not $\pi$

Therefore you final line is
$$\therefore4θ=\pm\cfrac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi$$
After removing the duplicates, four solutions remain.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos4\theta=\cos\dfrac\pi3$$

$$\implies4\theta=2n\pi\pm\dfrac\pi3=\dfrac\pi3(6n\pm1)$$ where $n$ is any integer

$$\implies\theta=\dfrac\pi{12}(6n+1)$$ where $n=-2,-1,0,1$

$\cos\dfrac\pi{12}(6\cdot-2+1)=\cos\left(\pi-\dfrac\pi{12}\right)=-\cos\dfrac\pi{12}$ etc.